# Google Sheet Date and Time Calculation Question

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a column that has 34 records of Week Day, Month/Day, and Times. I am looking for two formulas that I can use in a table that will give me the count of weekdays and the time duration per day. Eventually, I would like to just copy and past new dates into column A and have the table automatically calculate. Here is my google sheet example. Is there a way to do this without creating helper columns? If not, no big deal. Anything to help automate the process will be helpful.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6N94QJyEgm-2yg2SEDOweIU2fk2h2DLydKb-nH-ObE/edit?usp=sharing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3dFC.png)

Comment: Looking at your sheet I suggest you break col A into separate cols, day of week, date and duration. Otherwise, you will need to parse needlessly. I am also not clear on what you mean by duration as I think of duration as the time between to times, a start time and an end time.

Comment: Regarding the duration for Monday that was A6 1:23pm minus A2 12:49pm which is 33in.

Comment: I built an sample sheet that you can make a copy of if you like.

Comment: You can also find it helpful to convert from MM:SS to seconds (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821500/2371987). Just thought to share this, as it may give some support to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Punches tab in the sample sheet below. It shows what I was mentioning about breaking the columns up. Then, using the QUERY() function I was able to populate the table.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=1181136581

[image]

G6 Formula

```
=if(isna(query($A$1:$C, "SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B ='"&F2&"' LABEL COUNT(B) ''",1)),0,query($A$1:$C, "SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B ='"&F2&"' LABEL COUNT(B) ''",1))
```

H6 Formula

```
=if(G2<>0,query($A$1:$C, "SELECT C WHERE B ='"&F2&"' ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT 1 LABEL C ''",1)-query($A$1:$C, "SELECT C WHERE B ='"&F2&"' ORDER BY C LIMIT 1 LABEL C ''",1),0)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. I will make sure to study up more on the Google Sheet Query function. 

THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Would it be possible to have the table calculate based on another criteria? In a copy of your sheet, I added a new column that has two fields "Applied" and "Application Queue"

Ideally if I could have one table that showed the count of days and time duration for all the "Applied" and another table below it for "Application Queue" that would solve my whole issue.


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kw44YEnZszCHP_zbHX9C2XRY44csQ-MQt-f3ZkXs0bw/edit#gid=1181136581

Comment: If you would please vote this up as you said it was what you were looking for.

Comment: I think I have a quick fix to this I concatenated columns B & D. Probably not the best way, but it will serve its purpose. 

I would eventually like to add a criteria and select from a dynmic date range.

Comment: If you would please vote this up as you said it was what you were looking for.

Is your applied and queue option possible, just about anything is possible with a little thought and work. Even my solution is not the ony way to accomplish the task you needed. In this case, take a look at the "WHERE" clause in the query string. It is easy enough to add " AND D = 'Applied'"

QUERY() is modeled after SQL, it is not a complete implementation but still very powerful stuff.

I use https://www.w3schools.com/ whenever I need to learn about SQL, javascript, HTML, etc

Comment: Also, Ben Collins has many free articles and he is a sheets guru. This link is to the QUERY() function, he also has one for filtering using dates which is a bit tricky. https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/